# Pandas if value is equal to 1, then give column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
   Blue  Red
0   0     0
1   1     0
2   0     1
3   0     0
4   0     0
```

I want to say if value equals 1, then give the column name. So the expected output is

```
   Blue  Red
0   0     0
1   Blue  0
2   0     Red
3   0     0
4   0     0
```

I almost done this in a very complicated way, I was hoping there was a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with convert `columns` to Series for avoid `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_info_axis_number'` (in some newer pandas versions):

```
df = df.mask(df.eq(1), df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
print (df)
   Blue  Red
0     0    0
1  Blue    0
2     0  Red
3     0    0
4     0    0
```

Alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.eq(1), df.columns, df), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   Blue  Red
0     0    0
1  Blue    0
2     0  Red
3     0    0
4     0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by iteration over columns and rows:
Consider the dataframe is df1:

```
for name in df1.columns:
    for row in df1.index:
        if df1.loc[row,name] == 1:
            df1.loc[row,name] = name

print(df1)
   Blue  Red
0     0    0
1  Blue    0
2     0  Red
3     0    0
4     0    0
```